# (iOS) What resolution image for an image view with proportional constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

If I create an image view that has constraints that are proportional to the size of the screen. I can't decide the exact dimensions of image I need to supply for any of x1, x2 or x3. I understand how image sets work. But it's figuring out the dimensions I need because when I the following code I get slightly different dimensions for every device I test on:

```
 print(imageView.bounds.size.width)
 print(imageView.bounds.size.height)
```

Different x2 devices like the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 will give me slight differences. But because they receive the same image, will it not look different?

Comment: Note that Xcode also supports vector graphics if you don't feel like providing specific resolutions

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an `Aspect Ratio` constraint on your `UIImageView` to make sure you don't stretch the image.
2. Use `Aspect Fill` or `Aspect Fit` content mode for `UIImageView`.
3. Keep the biggest image for each scale factor (2x, 3x). Basically, there are multiple device resolutions for 2x scale factor, so @2x image should have resolution designed for iPhone 6 and it will be automatically downscaled on smaller devices (iPhone 5/4s). 3x image should have resolution for